# AWS Load Balancer AccessToken expired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a C#/.NET Framework ASP.NET MVC web application running in an Amazon EC2 instance. It is behind a Load Balancer that authenticates using Azure AD (OIDC).

I am using the access token header (`X-Amzn-Oidc-accesstoken`) to send emails via the Microsoft Graph API on behalf of the signed-in user.

My issue is that the access token retrieved from Load Balancer expires after about an hour.

How do I get the Load Balancer to request a new access token once it has expired? Is there something I should be doing from within my application that will cause the Load Balancer to refresh its token?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.